# how to capture the mouse idle state in Master Page Iframe in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using a Master page and many other pages from different folders are displayed in the IFrame within the master page.
If the user is not doing anything for some time [5 minutes or so] in any of the other pages, I want to give an alert message either to continue or to log out.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For example `setTimout` in jsvascript on `mouseover` for your iFrame. On each `mouseover` drop your timeout with `clearTimeout` and create new one.

But I don't think it's a good idea. Better to handle session timeout on the server. More info about sessions state you can find here: [ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)

After session ending user might me autmatically logged of and will be requested to login next time on any action whitch post request to the server.